# Using RoboSpice with Jackson2 and Spring

Tags: android, jackson, robospice

I want to use Jackson2 with `SpringRoboSpice` . 
my libs folder contains the following jars .

- commons-io-1.3.2.jar
- commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
- jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
- jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
- robospice-1.4.11.jar
- robospice-cache-1.4.11.jar
- robospice-spring-android-1.4.11.jar
- spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
- spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar

as written [here](https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/issues/61) `SpringAndroidSpiceService` will switch to `jackson2` if jackson2 jars found.

the app crash with this exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper
            at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.java:54)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService.createRestTemplate(JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService.java:33)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.SpringAndroidSpiceService.onCreate(SpringAndroidSpiceService.java:26)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2572)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
```

What i am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use Jackson 2, then you need to use a [`Jackson2SpringAndroidSpiceService`](http://octo-online.github.io/robospice/site/latest/apidocs/com/octo/android/robospice/Jackson2SpringAndroidSpiceService.html) and not a `JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService`. The 2 matters :)

Comment: i did that and when i run the app  an exception occur with  no service defined com.octo.android.robospice.JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService in manifest !!!

Comment: Double check the spice service used by your spice manager and declare the required service inside your manifest.

Comment: i did it but the error keep thrown  java.lang.RuntimeException: Impossible to start SpiceManager as no service of class : com.octo.android.robospice.JacksonSpringAndroidSpiceService is registered in AndroidManifest.xml file !
            at com.octo.android.robospice.SpiceManager.checkServiceIsProperlyDeclaredInAndroidManifest(SpiceManager.java:1278)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.SpiceManager.tryToStartService(SpiceManager.java:1161)
            at com.octo.android.robospice.SpiceManager.run(SpiceManager.java:243)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Comment: in manifest this is the service 
   <service
            android:name="com.octo.android.robospice.Jackson2SpringAndroidSpiceService"
            android:exported="false" />

Comment: Check which service is used by you spice manager, it appears to be using jackson 1 service